# JQuery Date Validation to check for first of every month

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am Using Jquery Validation and I am trying to do the date validation so that users can only enter the 1st of every month as a valid date, so for example 08/01/2012 would be a valid date but not 08/02/2012.

Right now I have the following code, which is just doing the basic date check is there a rule that i can add so it checks for the date to be the first of every month? Thank you in advance!

```
 <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#formID").validate({
                         rules: {

                             CurrentEligibleEmployees: {
                                  required: true,
                                  number: true},

                            EstimatedEnrolledEmployees: {
                                  required: true,
                                  number: true},

                                DesiredEffectiveDate: {
                                      required: true,
                                      date: true},

                                PlanAnniversaryStartDate: {
                                      required: true,
                                      date: true},

                                      PlanAnniversaryEndDate:{
                                           required: true,
                                            date: true}
                              }     

                         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You dont need jquery for this, just split the date string using `/` as separator. Then make sure the first one is a valid month, the second is always 1, and the third one is a valid year. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I would not let the user input the date, but only the month and the year. You can make a month picker from jquery ui datepicker. Here is what I did once:

monthpicker.js:

```
$.fn.monthpicker = function()
{
  var element = $(this);

  element.datepicker(
  {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm',
    onClose: function()
    {
      var widget = get_widget();

      var month = widget.find(".ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
      var year = widget.find(".ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();

      element.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));

      widget.hide().removeClass("monthpicker");
    },
    beforeShow : function()
    {
      get_widget().addClass("monthpicker");

      var datestr = element.val();

      if (datestr.length > 0)
      {
        var date = datestr.split('-');

        year = date[0];
        month = date[1] - 1;

        element.datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month));
        element.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month));
      }
    }
  });

  function get_widget()
  { return element.datepicker("widget"); }
};
```

monthpicker.css

```
.monthpicker .ui-datepicker-calendar{
        display: none;
}
```

So now you have an

```
<input type="text" id="themonth">
```

and in script you do this:

```
$('#themonth').monthpicker();
```

But the date format is maybe something you need to change becuase I have used YYYY-MM